# How to add an array to a column of CSV file using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have stored a set of four numbers in an array which I want to add to a CSV file under the 'Score' column. Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What sort of code have you already tried?  Can you show us what you have now?

Comment: with open('Playerout.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['No.', 'Score','Salary']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Score': score[0]})
    writer.writerow({'Score': score[1]})
    writer.writerow({'Score': score[2]})                                                                     I have tried doing this, but it appends the data leaving one line in the middle. @Castaglia

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. One solution would be to place Score at the end. The only quick 'solution' I think is to 'model' your data like this:

```
game_id, score_1 {,..., score_n}
```

So you don't have to care about scores' array size, since all the next values after game_id will be scores.

(Note that this is a quick fix example for your problem. I dont know your data model and probably you will have to modify things, but you've my approach)

Also when your data model becomes harder, it's not good idea to work with files. Consider storing your data into a database like SQLite or whatever.